# Unable to display header tags with query data

Tags: reactjs, api, schema, searchbar

I have been trying to display two of the properties for search results but neither of them show up on the app when the user submits the query (item.brand and item.toolName from the h3 headings). I was able to display a just one of the two properties by changing the setResults to only search for item.toolName or item.brand but how do I get both the properties to be displayed when the user submits a query?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';

function Searchbar() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const userInput = event.target.value;
    setInput(userInput);
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setQuery(input);
  };

  // When the query state changes ([query]), we then run the effect
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/tools/?q=${query}`);
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log({ json });
        setResults(
          json.data.map((item) => {
            return item;
          })
        );
      } catch (error) {}
    }

    if (query !== '') {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [query]);

  return (
    // <Fragment>
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Enter something'
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={input}
        />

        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br />
      {results
        .filter((item) => {
          if (query === '') {
            return item;
          } else if (item.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            return item;
          }
        })
        .map((item, id) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <h3>{item.brand}</h3>
            <h3>{item.toolName}</h3>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    // </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Searchbar;
```

Comment: How are you trying to use the `toLowerCase` method on an object?

Comment: That was the issue, I was targeting the entire object instead of the property. I tried changing the toolName property toLowerCase inside the object and that worked. Thanks for the help!